# 301 redirect for all pages with specific url pattern

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Want to redirect all the pages with specific url pattern to my new homepage

Redirect all request with below pattern

---

```
 http://somesite.com/pages/homepage/<Anything>
```

Sample URL TO BE REDIRECTED

---

```
 http://somesite.com/pages/homepage/?pn=1&cat=71
```

New page to be redirected

---

```
 http://somesite.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule as your first rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pages/homepage(/.*)?$ /? [L,NC,R=301]
```